# EntityFramework navigation property not working as expected

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have the following 3 (simplified) classes setup in entity framework

```
public class Service
{
    [Key]
    public int ServiceId { get; set; }
    public int WorkformId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("WorkformId")]
    public virtual Workform Workform { get; set; }
}


public class Workform
{
    [Key]
    public int WorkformId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("WorkformId")]
    public virtual ICollection<FieldMap> FieldMaps { get; set; }
 }


public class FieldMap
{
    [Key]
    public int FieldMapId{ get; set; }
    public int WorkformId{ get; set; }
 }
```

And if I try to do something like this

```
var service = db.Services.Include("Workform.FieldMaps")
                .FirstOrDefault(p => p.ServiceId == serviceId);
```

service.Workform.FieldMaps is pulling the entire collection, not just the records with the matching relational id.

Am I missing some here?

Comment: The above looks ok (only `ForeignKey` attribute on the `FieldMaps` collection is redundant). EF6 or EF Core?

Comment: This is using EF6

Comment: Can't reproduce with the above model. Everything works as expected.

Comment: The problem becomes obvious once FieldMap contains records with different WorkformIds. service.Workform.FieldMaps pulls all the FieldMap records, not just the related ones

Comment: @user1691808 how does it happen? If you map your entities correctly, this should never happen. Can you provide entity mappings for those entities and scenario, when your problem with pulling all FieldMap entities happen?